# Loading HTML file with JavaScript vs having long file content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, single-page-application, jquery-load

I'm redesigning application that could be a good fit for SPA. After reviewing the code I found that previous developers used `JQuery/JavaScript load()` method to include `.html` files. For example they have `header.html` and `footer.html`. On page load `.html` are loading in div containers. Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>App Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
// Body content
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#header').load('includes/header.html');
    $('#footer').load('includes/footer.html');
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In this case loading `.html` doesn't have any impact on JavaScript events since none of the elements in these two files have events. In case for example if I put `onClick` function in one of the elements in `header.html` that will be a problem. The DOM content will load before `script` on the bottom of the `body` tag. I have questions about this methods:

1. Is it a good approach to load `.html` files using JavaScript for
   this purpose?
2. Is there any reason to load `.html` with JavaScript
       other than cleaner code and easier maintenance?
3. If there are
       benefits of loading `.html` with JavaScript, how to prevent race
       condition in case where DOM is loaded before script content?

I'm trying to understand why this approach would be a good option and if that is a good practice now days in Web Development of Single Page Applications. Another thing that I forgot to mention is that I only use front end languages for this project. There is no server-side language involved.

Comment: try with $( window ).load(function() {
  // Run code
});